# Not able to get the SKU details in app purchase through Google Play Store

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am trying to get Product details from Google play store, But always I am getting response code 0 and DETAILS_LIST empty. Please let me know if anyone has idea on below. Thanks for your response.

1. APK is published for USA, not for India, can I test from here if yes which all are things I need to take care?
2. In some blog I have found that published APK doesn't take effect immediately, for how much time I will have to wait.

public class GetSkuDetails extends Activity implements
        IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener {
    Context mContext;
    private IabHelper billingHelper;

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    billingHelper = new IabHelper(this, AppProperties.BASE_64_KEY);
    billingHelper.startSetup(this);
}

public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        SkuDetails sku = billingHelper.getSkuDetails("tier2",
                IabHelper.ITEM_TYPE_INAPP);
        if (sku != null) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, sku.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Log.d(" calling asynchronous to get sku detail");
            getSku("tier2");
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
    }
}

protected void getSku(final String skuID){
    List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
    skuList.add(skuID);
    billingHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, skuList, new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inv) {
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                Log.d(inv.toString() + " + " + inv.hasDetails(Passport.SKU));
                SkuDetails sku = inv.getSkuDetails(skuID);
                Log.d("onQueryInventoryFinished result = " + result.isSuccess() + " sku = " + sku);
                if (sku != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, sku.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? Does it just take google a long time to get the products available to access?